# Django Auth - Unhash the hashed password

Tags: django, authentication

I have two server and one is using Django.

My auth flow is that Server A(using Django) if the user submit the right account & password

Then Server A will pass the password to Server B update the password.

So how can I unhash the password in Django DB and pass the raw password to the Server B?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't be able to. If __you__ can unhash/decrypt a users password then an __attacker can too__

Comment: So you mean I just pass the hash to Server B. If one day I am going to reverse the Auth flow using Server B first then what kind of function I can use to verify the hash?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the login details between applications? You should probably have 1 centralised authentication application/method

Comment: What do you mean by two servers? Do you have two separate Django applications sharing the same user directory? In that case it makes more sense to use a central authentication server. You can implement your own or use a 3rd party such as auth0.

Comment: Currently I am using the ASP with raw password under MSSQL. I would like to add one more new server which is going to use Django. The auth flow would be check Django first then update the ASP

Comment: I know it is stupid to store the raw password through ASP in MSSQL. But it's my boss request and I have to do it if I am going to use Django~

Comment: First, it's extremely irresponsible, immoral and against all best security practices that have been worked on for years to do what you are asking. You also could potentially land you/the company you work for in trouble if you do not store passwords securely. Second, you can add your own auth views that will get the raw username/password POST data from the user, you can then do with this what you want... but seriously don't store user's passwords in plain text or any other format that you can recover the raw password easily